# Wiring an electrical outlet under a sink with 2 black wires a red wire and 2 white wires but 1 white wire is hot

Tags: receptacle

I am replacing an electrical outlet under the sink that connects to a garbage disposal switch. There are five wires, 2 black wires (hot), 1 red wire that I believe connects to the garbage disposal switch, a ground wire, and 2 white wires but one of the white wires is hot.
How do I connect these wires to the electrical outlet. Can I pigtail the hot wires ( 2 black and 1 white) together and attach it to a brass colored screw,the red wire to the other brass colored screw of the outlet, and the white neutral to the opposite side of the red wire, meaning the silver colored screw?
I would appreciate your professional advice

Thank you, Jaime

Comment: Check how the switch is wired.  Was there a tab between the two screws on the hot/brass side of the old outlet?

Comment: How was the old outlet wired?  Do you have a dishwasher that plugs into the outlet as well?  A hot water dispenser?

Comment: Don't disconnect anything until you take a lot of pictures.

Comment: Are you using a voltmeter to determine "hot", and relative to what? Non-contact testers can be fooled.